# Golang http.NewRequest: Invalid content-type

Tags: struct, go

I am trying to post a `struct` using Go's `http.POST`, however I am not being succeeded with that.

Please look:

```
//SKUStock definition
type SkuStock struct {
    Sku string `json:"id"`;
    Quantity int64 `json:"stockQuantity"`;
}

type StockJson struct {
    Items []SkuStock `json:"skus"`;
}
```

After loading some data from a database, I have the following, in order to perform the POST itself:

```
//Sends the skuStock Information to server
func SendSkuData(stockItems []SkuStock) {

//creates a json like {"skus":[{"id":"ITEM1576","stockQuantity":995}]}
    stockPayload, err := json.Marshal(StockJson{stockItems}); 
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err);
    }

    client := &http.Client{}

    apiRequestUrl := os.Getenv("api.protocol") + "://" + os.Getenv("api.address") + "/batch/sku/stock";
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", apiRequestUrl, bytes.NewBuffer(stockPayload));
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
    req.SetBasicAuth(os.Getenv("api.key"), "");

    log.Printf("Request body: %s", string(stockPayload));
    log.Printf("Request %s", req);

    resp, err := client.Do(req);
    if(err != nil) {
        log.Fatal(err);
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close();

    log.Printf("Response %s", resp);

}
```

Unfortunately, the return I get from server is not as expected:

```
2015/12/08 23:42:47 Request body: {"skus":[{"id":"ITEM1576","stockQuantity":995}]}
2015/12/08 23:42:47 Request &{POST http://api-sandbox.bonmarketplace.com.br/batch/sku/stock HTTP/1.1 %!s(int=1) %!s(    int=1) map[Authorization:[Basic REMzRjAyNjUwNDE5RDAzQUJBNjEyM0E0QUZCMzJGQUQ6] Content-Type:[application/    json;charset=utf-8]] {{"skus":[{"id":"ITEM1576","stockQuantity":995}]}} %!s(int64=48) [] %!s(bool=false) api-sandbox.    bonmarketplace.com.br map[] map[] %!s(*multipart.Form=<nil>) map[]   %!s(*tls.ConnectionState=<nil>) %!s(<-chan struct     {}=<nil>)}
2015/12/08 23:42:47 Response &{415 Unsupported Media Type %!s(int=415) HTTP/1.1 %!s(int=1) %!s(int=1) map[Server:[    nginx/1.7.5] Date:[Wed, 09 Dec 2015 01:40:18 GMT] Content-Type:[application/json;charset=utf-8] Content-Length:[163]     Connection:[keep-alive] X-Access-Control-Realm:[external]] %!s(*http.bodyEOFSignal=&{0xc820122000 {0 0} false <nil>     0xd78a0 0xd7840}) %!s(int64=163) [] %!s(bool=false) map[] %!s(*http.Request=&{POST 0xc820064480 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-    Type:[application/json;charset=utf-8] Authorization:[Basic REMzRjAyNjUwNDE5RDAzQUJBNjEyM0E0QUZCMzJGQUQ6]] {0xc82000e460}     48 [] false api-sandbox.bonmarketplace.com.br map[] map[] <nil> map[]   <nil> <nil>}) %!s(*tls.ConnectionState=<nil>)}
```

**Edit**: inserted the post body(first line on program's output). If I run the request on Postman, with this body, it works as expected. Server does not check `Accept` header, just the `Content-Type`, which is already set to `application/json;charset=utf-8`.

What am I doing wrong? I have spent the last hours looking into this, but no luck at all.

Comment: Couple things; can you check the accepts headers on the server? Little search says this will occur if the content-type supplied in the request doesn't match one in the accepts headers. Secondly, can you please get the body into a string and print it and include that output? It might have something more useful like a message written by one of the API's developers.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal tks for your reply. Just inserted the return body on code. I checked on server and it does not expect an `Accept` header. I tested using postman(using the post body generated by the above code) and it works as expected.

Comment: OK, yeah the bit about accepts headers doesn't make sense, I was thinking they're coming from the server but that's in the request. For the body I meant the response body, not the request.

Comment: Perhaps the server has a faulty media type parser. Try "application/json;  charset=utf-8"  (note the space after ;) and "application/json".

Comment: @CodingPickle @evanmcdonnal: Thanks a lot! Just found the answer. After printing the response.body, I found a message stating that the Content-Type should be set to `application/json;charset=UTF-8`(in upper case). The original header was set to `utf-8`(in lower case), which was causing all the trouble. Just realised I really need to take some nap after that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After printing the response body, the following has been returned:

```
2015/12/09 00:32:11 Response Body {"httpStatusCode":415,"errorCode":"415","message":"Content-type:[application/json;charset=utf-8] invalido. Utilizar content-type:[application/json;charset=UTF-8]"}
```

From portuguese: "Invalid Content-Type. Please use `application/json;charset=UTF-8`.

The detail was in the case used on `UTF-8` string, which should be uppercase, not lower as previously. Thanks @evanmcdonnal and @CodingPickle for support.